# Capistrano Rails deploy with new migration files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano

I want to deploy from a new branch I have created. On this branch, the db/migrate content has changed, I removed some migration files and regenerated a new one.

The problem is, when I `cap staging deploy` from this branch, it fails when running migrations `PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "partners" already exists`.

I want to run `rake db:drop` and `rake db:setup` on the server(no real data), but first I need to have an updated content in my `app_name/current/db/migrate` folder.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up disabling `require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'` from my Capfile and ran `rake db:drop rake db:setup` from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can override cap db:migrations in `config/deploy.rb` by adding

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "No ActiveRecord override"
  task :migrate do
  end
end
```

This way when you deploy it won't run the migrations, then you can go to the server and run rake tasks for dropping and resetting the database.

Note: It is not advisable that you edit, delete any migration files. Just create a new migration if you want to edit any columns or tables.